# Derivative of $f(t)=\frac {1}{\rho}\log (1+\rho t)$

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Could you have me to find the ferivative of $$f(t)=\frac {1}{\rho}\log (1+\rho t)$$ with repsect to $t$?

And Is it 
$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac {f'(t)}{t}=1?$$
*Update:*
Based on Hint of Surb:

$$f(t)'=\frac {1}{1+\rho t}$$

Then 
$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac {f'(t)}{t}=0$$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(t)=\frac {1}{\rho}\ln (1+\rho t)\Longrightarrow$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac {1}{\rho}\ln (1+\rho t)\right)=$$
$$\frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\ln (1+\rho t)\right)}{\rho}=$$
$$\frac{\frac{\frac{d}{dt} (1+\rho t)}{1+\rho t}}{\rho}=$$
$$\frac{\frac{d}{dt} (1+\rho t)}{\rho (1+\rho t)}=$$
$$\frac{\frac{d}{dt} (1)+\frac{d}{dt}(\rho t))}{\rho (1+\rho t)}=$$
$$\frac{0+\rho\frac{d}{dt}(t))}{\rho (1+\rho t)}=$$
$$\frac{0+\rho\cdot 1)}{\rho (1+\rho t)}=$$
$$\frac{\rho}{\rho (1+\rho t)}=$$
$$\frac{1}{1+\rho t}$$

So:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac {1}{\rho}\ln (1+\rho t)\right)=\frac{1}{1+\rho t}$$

---

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\frac{f'(t)}{t}\right)=\lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\frac{\frac{1}{1+\rho t}}{t}\right)=\lim_{t \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{t+\rho t^2}\right)=0$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$$\Big(\log(u(t))\Big)'=\frac{u'(t)}{u(t)}$$

Comment: Thank Surb. I updated my answer. Is it correct?

Comment: @user3051460 It is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, we have $$f(t)=\frac {1}{\rho}\log (1+\rho t)$$  Now, differentiating both the sides w.r.t. $t$ by applying chain-rule as follows
$$\frac{d}{dt}(f(t))=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac {1}{\rho}\log (1+\rho t)\right)$$  $$f'(t)=\frac{1}{\rho}\frac {1}{(1+\rho t)}\frac{d}{dt}(1+\rho t)$$ $$=\frac{1}{\rho}\frac {1}{(1+\rho t)}(\rho)$$   $$\color{blue}{f'(t)=\frac {1}{1+\rho t}}$$